# Django template syntax error: could not parse remainder % 2

Tags: django-templates

I am getting a `TemplateSyntaxError`: "could not parse remainder % 2 from num%2":

```
{% if num%2 ==0 %}
   {{"Even"}}
{% else %}
   {{"Odd"}}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use arbitrary Python expressions in Django templates. You should [create a custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) for them.

However, for your expression there is a built-in tag [divisibleby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby). From its example:

```
{{ value|divisibleby:"2" }}
```

If value is 4, the output would be True. So the final answer looks like (untested):

```
{% if num|divisibleby:"2" %}
    Even
{% else %}
    Odd
{% endif %}
```